# Scala Puzzle: enforcing that two function arguments are of the same type AND both are a subtype of a given class

Tags: scala, types, compilation, type-inference, type-systems

How can I enforce that `trickyMethod`'s arguments are the same at compile time but at the same time also have the common super type `Fruit` ?

So in other words, `tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple)` should not compile.

I am sure there must be a simple solution but I just spent 1 hour searching for the answer and still have no idea :(

I tried implicit evidence with <:< but I could not get it to work.

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit

class TrickyClass[T<:Fruit]{
  def trickyMethod(p1:T,p2:T)= println("I am tricky to solve!")
}

object TypeInferenceQuestion extends App{
  val tricky=new TrickyClass[Fruit]()
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Apple,new Apple) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Banana) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile

}
```

EDIT :

Thank you for the answers !

**Follow up (more general) question:**

This second example is a more general case of the first example.

```
class Fruit

class Apple extends Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit

class TrickyClass[T]{
  def trickyMethod[S<:T](p1:S,p2:S)= println("I am tricky to solve!")
}

object TypeInferenceQuestion extends App{
  val tricky=new TrickyClass[Fruit]()
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Apple,new Apple) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Banana) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile

}
```

Comment: Surely you want the generic parameters to go on `trickyMethod` instead of `TrickyClass`? You are explicitly allowing `T` to be `Fruit` in the definition of `tricky`.

Comment: Yes, that is my intention. (This is a simple example that exhibits the same problem which popped up in a more complicated problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do :

```
class Tricky[T] {
  def trickyMethod[S1<:T,S2<:T](s1:S1,s2:S2)(implicit ev: S1=:=S2) = println()
}


scala> val t = new Tricky[Seq[Int]]
t: Tricky[Seq[Int]] = Tricky@2e585191

scala> t.trickyMethod(List(1),List(1))
//OK

scala> t.trickyMethod(List(1),Seq(1))
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] =:= Seq[Int].
              t.trickyMethod(List(1),Seq(1))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I could even write this 2 chars shorter:  def trickyMethod[S1,S2<:T](p1:S1,p2:S1) (implicit ev:S1=:=S2) = println("I am tricky to solve!") Great! This simple solution answers both questions.

Comment: For anyone else as baffled as I about "=:=" - it's in Predef.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with implicits like so.  Keep in mind that you will always be able to

```
tricky.trickyMethod((new Banana): Fruit, (new Apple): Fruit)
```

since disallowing that would break the subtyping relationship.  (If really necessary, you could use [Miles Sabin's encoding of "not this type"](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) (see comment #38) to reject `Fruit`.)

Anyway, one way to achieve what you want is as follows:

```
class SamePair[T,U] {}
object SamePair extends SamePair[Nothing,Nothing] {
  def as[A] = this.asInstanceOf[SamePair[A,A]]
}
implicit def weAreTheSame[A] = SamePair.as[A]
```

Now we have an implicit that will give us a dummy object that verifies that two types are the same.

So now we change `TrickyClass` to

```
class TrickyClass[T <: Fruit] {
  def trickyMethod[A <: T, B <: T](p1: A, p2: B)(implicit same: SamePair[A,B]) = println("!")
}
```

And it does what you want:

```
scala>  val tricky=new TrickyClass[Fruit]()
tricky: TrickyClass[Fruit] = TrickyClass@1483ce25

scala>   tricky.trickyMethod(new Apple,new Apple) //this should be OK
!

scala>   tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Banana) //this should be OK
!

scala>   tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter same: SamePair[Banana,Apple]
                tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile
```

Comment: Nice answer. And you have done well to warn about the fact that sub-typing relationships mean that we cannot really prevent the caller to pass two instances with different (runtime) types. But your phrasing makes it look like using Miles Sabin's encoding of "not this type" would prevent the problem (but it would not, it's just a tool enabling another way to write essentially the same constraints as you have done manually here)

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - You can encode "not `Fruit`" with it.  That's all.  Not "these are the same", just "not `Fruit`".  If everything that is not `Fruit` is a leaf class, that's enough (in addition to the "same" encoding).  Otherwise, you are out of luck, depending on what you want.

Comment: Sure, if those are leaf classes the problem goes away (both using your encoding of the constraints or using Miles Sabin's encoding of "not this type"). My point was just that conversely if those are not leaf classes the problem regarding sub-typing is the same in both encodings.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
abstract class Fruit[T <: Fruit[T]] {
  def trick(that: T)
}

class Apple extends Fruit[Apple] {
  override def trick(that: Apple) = { println("Apple") }
}

class Banana extends Fruit[Banana] {
  override def trick(that: Banana) = { println("Banana") }
}

class TrickyClass{
  def trickyMethod[T<:Fruit[T]](p1:T,p2:T)= p1.trick(p2)
}

object TypeInferenceQuestion {
  val tricky=new TrickyClass()
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Apple,new Apple) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Banana) //this should be OK
  tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile
}
```

it gives:

```
error: inferred type arguments [Fruit[_ >: Apple with Banana <: Fruit[_ >: Apple with Banana <: ScalaObject]]] do not conform to method trickyMethod's type parameter bounds [T <: Fruit[T]]
         tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile
```

On the last one.

Comment: This is the only answer that gets a vote from me - much cleaner than implicits, and a common pattern in Java generics.

Comment: Can this solution be generalised to solve the second (more general) problem ?

Comment: @EdStaub - I find this pattern very ugly since it introduces a generic parameter to `Fruit` which now needs to be propagated to everywhere that deals with them, and also doesn't guarantee safety since you can do `class LyingFruit extends Fruit[Apple]`.

Comment: @jhegedus I can't think of any way to achieve that, I will edit my answer if I do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use implicits, although you will have to define one for each `Fruit` subclass:

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit

trait FruitEvidence[T <: Fruit]

class TrickyClass{
  def trickyMethod[T <: Fruit](p1:T,p2:T)(implicit e: FruitEvidence[T]) = println("I am tricky to solve!")
}

object FruitImplicits {
    implicit val BananaEvidence = new FruitEvidence[Banana] { }
    implicit val AppleEvidence = new FruitEvidence[Apple] { }
}

object TypeInferenceQuestion extends App{
      import FruitImplicits._
      val tricky=new TrickyClass()
      tricky.trickyMethod(new Apple,new Apple) //this should be OK
      tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Banana) //this should be OK
      tricky.trickyMethod(new Banana,new Apple) //this should NOT compile
}
```